# Calling a method in java using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am getting following exception when calling a method using java reflection,

Let's say that I have follwing classes,

```
package hello;

public class SimpleService {

    public void SayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and this class is compressed into a jar file called hello.jar

then I am calling the SayHello() from another class in another jar called TestHello.jar which is a 
simple Swing application.

```
public class TestPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel{

.
.

jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
});

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            String jarPath = "/SayHello/SayHello" + ".jar";            
            URL[] classpathURLs = new URL[]{new File(jarPath).toURI().toURL()};
            ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(classpathURLs);
            Class helloClass = loader.loadClass("hello.SimpleService");           
            Method sayHello = helloClass.getMethod("SayHello");            
            int modifiers = sayHello.getModifiers();

            if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) {
               sayHello.invoke(this, null);
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchMethodException();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }        
}


}
.
.
```

above TestPanel class is also created using java reflection and then that panel will be added into
a JFrame.

all the things are working properly except when I click the jButton1 I get following exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    .
    .
    .
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Can you specify which exact line throws that exception?

Comment: sayHello.invoke(this, null); line throws the excetion.

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string. `this` is not an instance of SimpleService in your invocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sayHello.invoke(this, null);
```

The first argument is supposed to be a `SimpleService`. Change it to:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), null);
```

---

For clarity you may change your code like this:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), (Object[]) null);
```

or this:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance());
```

Otherwise it may be misinterpreted as:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), (Object) null);
```

or this:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), new Object[]{null});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SayHello` method takes no arguments, so when calling it reflectively, don't pass anything except the instance. Also, the first parameter should be an instance of SimpleService:

Replace this:

```
sayHello.invoke(this, null);
```

with this:

```
sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

sure, "this" is of type TestPanel and not of type SimpleService

Try the following:

```
   Class helloClass = loader.loadClass("hello.SimpleService");           

   Object args1[] = new Object[] {};
   Constructor<SimpleService> constructor = helloClass.getConstructor(args1);
   Object simpleService = constructor.newInstance();       

   sayHello.invoke(simpleService, null);
```

or shorter

```
   Class helloClass = loader.loadClass("hello.SimpleService");                 
   sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), null);
```

Comment: You can directly say `Object simpleService = helloClass.newInstance()`.

Comment: right sayHello.invoke(helloClass.newInstance(), null); is also working

Answer (score 0):

Notice this line: `sayHello.invoke(this, null);`

when using `Method.invoke` you need to supply an instance of the `Class` of which the `Method` is an instance. So to call `sayHello.invoke` you need to supply an instance of `SimpleService`.

Secondly, since `SayHello` does not take any arguments, the call should be `sayHello.invoke(myinstance)`. Notice no second argument.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
sayHello.invoke(this, null);
```

`this` (`TestPanel`) is not an instance of `SimpleService`. You need an instance of `SimpleService` or you can make the `SayHello` method static:

```
public static void SayHello()
```

and then probably pass `null` instead for correctness: (["If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29))

```
sayHello.invoke(null, null);
```